# eval_set in xgboost and validation data

Tags: cross-validation, validation, boosting

In my understanding, if I am picking from a set of models, each with a different set of hyper-parameters, the proper way to approach it is like this: First, split the data to `train` and `val`. Then fit the model with `train`, and score it with the `val`. Then pick the model and hyper-parameters with the highest score, and re-train it using the combined set of `train` and `val`.

So for example if I am picking among knn models with k1, ..., k3 neighbours, and random forest models with a1, ..., a5 trees, I fit all `3 + 5 = 8` models with `train` and I score the result with `val`. I then pick the model with the best score, say knn with k2 neighbours, and re-train it with the `train` and `val` combined.

To this point I think my understanding is correct. But when I got to xgboost, I got really confused. 
In xgboost fitting function, there are two parameters that confuse me: `early_stopping_rounds` and `eval_set`. Based on the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), `eval_set` is a validation set. If the score based on `eval_set` does not improve in `early_stopping_rounds` rounds, the training stops and returns the result. My question is how can the validation data be used in the fitting process? I am thinking about two possibilities, but I am not sure which is correct, or if neither is:

**possibility 1**:
`eval_set` should be a subset of the train set. So continuing with the above example, I should split `train` to `train_for_train` and `train_for_val`,  and set `eval_set` as `train_for_val`. I should then score the model returned with the with the same `val` as my knn and random forest models.

**possibility 2**: `eval_set` doesn't affect how the trees are build, so it isn't technically used to fit the model. Therefore, there is less concern on over-fitting. `eval_set` affects how many rounds there is, which is effectively how many trees to use in the ensemble. In the same way that it is okay to use `val` to determine the optimal number of trees in random forest, it is also fine to use `val` to determine the optimal number of rounds in xgboost. So it's okay to set `eval_set` as `val` during model fitting, score the returned model with `val`, and compare the score with  the other knn and random forest models.

If possibility 2 is correct, my next question is: If xgboost with the automatically detected optimal number of rounds turns out to have the highest score in all the models, how do I re-train it with `train` and `val` ? I don't see the option for this hyper-parameter in the documentation.

Finally, I am also confused with how to use cross-validation with xgboost? If I let the model decide the best number of rounds using `eval_set` and `early_stopping_rounds`, the result would be different when I use different folds for train and validation. Or should I not use cross-validation if I am letting the model decide the hyper-parameters, and only use it when I am the one specifying the sets of hyper-parameters to choose from?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the following: You got to put the eval_set being equal to the set you are going evaluate the model in that moment. It means that if you are testing if some model gotten from XGBOOST its better than other, the eval_test would be the validation, that set that you splitted to make the hyperparameter search.

In a Nested Cross Validation for example, in the inside fold would be the "internal test set" and when you got to evaluate for performance of that model, you would use as eval_set the "external test set".

It's like to giving tô XGBOOST that given some unseen data, he'll have a tip for not training too much based on that unseen data, whoever could It be this unseen data, validation or test data.

For hyperparameter search it's like you are telling for all different models generated via hyperparameter search the following "okay guys, you all are training until you are not improving anymore on this validation set"

Answer (score 0):

Long and old question. Still quite relevant to others, I think.

### Question 1: Possibility 1 or 2

"Possibility 1" is clearly the more concise one, especially since you want to compete XGBoost against other algorithms. Selecting the optimal number of boosting rounds actively makes use of "eval_set". BTW: the same applies for the other big round-based algorithm: neural nets.

### How do I retrain with train and val?

You would fit the model to the combined data without early stopping, but using the optimal number of rounds from the best early-stopping model. There is no "parameter" for it.

### Cross-validation

Ideally, you combine early-stopping and CV. XGBoost has a "cv" method that boosts parallel over all folds, and evaluates the average performance over folds after each boosting round. The less concise alternative is that you boost each fold separately. Then you get an optimal number of boosting rounds per fold. You can choose how to combine them (take the average, maximum, minimum etc.). There is no official rule.